# Adjusting a value in a For/Next loop with an If/then statement

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

So I have a nice convoluted series of subs that are all connected with a userform. The code basically checks a date value stored in a tabled against today, stores that T/F answer in another table, and once each row meets a criteria of Trues, moves the date to another table to be viewed. It's this third table that's causing the problem. I want the new table to have everything listed contiguously here, but instead, all I can seem to do is copy it to the same cell on a different sheet.

```
Set ToDoRange = Sheets("ToDo").Range("A2")
 ToDoRow = 2
For i = 2 To LastRow 'Search each column in each row before moving to the next row

For Each ColVar In [PM].Columns

···
···
···

Set WorkReady = Sheets("DateList").Cells(i, j)


If LocChk2.Value = True And TFRange.Value = True And j > ColLoc Then

     With Sheets("DateList").Rows(i)
         .Interior.Color = 8257297
         .Copy
     End With
    Sheets("ToDo").Cells(ToDoRow, j) = WorkReady.Value
       With ToDoRange
        .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
       End With
 ElseIf LocChk2.Value = False Or TFRange.Value = False Or j <= ColLoc Then
          WorkReady.Interior.Color = 255
          With Sheets("ToDo").Cells(ToDoRow, j)
                .Clear
                .Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlMedium
                .Interior.Color = 16755623
          End With
          If j < ColNumber Then
          Sheets("ToDo").Cells(ToDoRow, j).Borders(xlEdgeBottom).Weight = xlNone
          End If


    End If

Next

'If Len(Sheets("ToDo").Cells(ToDoRow, ColLoc).Value) <> 0 Then

ToDoRow = ToDoRow + 1
Set ToDoRange = ToDoRange.Offset(1, 0) 
'End If
Next
```

When the If/Then statement at the bottom is enabled, it seems to randomly select what values it meet that criteria. If I move it between the two "for"s instead of the "next"s then it offsets all the values more like a staircase than a row. Any suggestions?

Update: if I sort the table so that everything is listed together, it crashes Excel the next time I run the sub.

Answer (score 0):

So it just crashed that one time, and I still don't know why it did that, but just automatically sorting it at the end of the code seems to have solved all of my issues.

```
Sheets("ToDo").ListObjects("Table1").Sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("Table1[[#All],[Number]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With Sheets("ToDo").ListObjects("Table1").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
```

It was a simple solution, and I spent longer than I'd like to admit before I remembered that you can sort tables.